# ObjectOutputStream not available in PlayerList.java - impossible to get data for table

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, javafx-8, scenebuilder

ok, again. Here a new project with the relevant code. As you can see in the textfield, even though initData should have initialized the testVar variable, it doesnt happen and in initialize() the variable is null. I need to get the variable there though, so i can get data off a network connection into a table. Here the code:

FXMLController.java:

```
package de.freakyonline.testproject;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class FXMLController implements Initializable {
    String testVar;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TextArea testTextArea;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // Here it's null    
        testTextArea.appendText("TestVar: " + testVar);

    }

    void initData(Remote remoteObj) {
        this.testVar = remoteObj.getVar();
    }    
}
```

MainApp.java:

```
package de.freakyonline.testproject;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application {
    Thread remote;
    Remote remoteObj;

    String testVar = new String("success");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader root = new FXMLLoader(
            getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml")
        );

        try {
            remoteObj = new Remote(testVar);
            remote = new Thread(remoteObj);
        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        remote.start();

        Scene scene = new Scene((Parent) root.load());
        FXMLController controller = root.<FXMLController>getController(); 
        controller.initData(remoteObj);

        scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

        stage.setTitle("TestProjects ...");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();


    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Scene.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="de.freakyonline.testproject.FXMLController">
   <center>
      <TextArea fx:id="testTextArea" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Remote.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package de.freakyonline.testproject;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author uwe
 */
public class Remote implements Runnable {
    private String testVar;

    public Remote (String testVar) {
        this.testVar = testVar;
    }

    public String getVar() {
        return testVar;
    }

    public void run() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to the relevant part, as nobody wants to read pages of code

Comment: done :) thank you.

Comment: Try backwards tracing from which point on it is null

Comment: i did. its null from PlayerList playerList = new PlayerList(in,out,sock,consoleOneTextArea); it looks like it wasnt initialized yet - when the initialize method gets called. but this was suggested to me at least for the consoleTextArea. So I thouhgt I can use it for this too. I can't see another way to do it. Because putting code into the initialize function also wont help me as out is null there too.

Comment: Since you create the out object right before calling initData it can't be null when calling it, however you say it is null in the method initData, this means the only way this could be is if your method `getOut()` isn't working

Comment: hm i made an edit, at the bottom: EDIT: Remote.java ... it should work as, the remote object behaves normaly, and gets data from in and sends to out.

Comment: Ok have you then checked also the LogCat to see if the catch block in MainApp gets called because it couldn't build a connection or similar?

Comment: ^well yes, i can in consoleOneTextField write: testserver and it sends/recieves data.

Comment: You have gone from way too much code, to not enough code for anyone to really understand what is going on. You should try to create a [MCVE]. (Please read the link and understand what it is saying.) This usually means creating a new project from scratch that has *only* the features of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You keep saying 'not available' as though it means something. It doesn't. What is your question?

Comment: ok ive changed the code i hope its ok now. my question is, how can I have the testVar inside initialize() in FXMLController initialized so I can instantly get the table data off the network connection?

Comment: I hope someone can help me because I really wanna get this program to work ;D.

Comment: *Much* improved question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controller's `initialize()` method is called by the `FXMLLoader` when the FXML is loaded, i.e. it is called during the invocation of `load()`. In your example code, you call `initData()` *after* you call `load()`, so clearly `testVar` cannot have been initialized when the `initialize()` method is executed. Since the controller in the example code is created by the `FXMLLoader`, you cannot call `initData(...)` before `initialize()` is called.

(Aside: using some simple debugging techniques, such as using a step-through debugger, or even just printing a message when each method is invoked, would make it very clear what the issue is here.)

The easiest fix is just to move the code that depends on `testVar` to the `initData()` method (or some other method that is called *after* `testVar` is initialized):

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {
    String testVar;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TextArea testTextArea;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

    void initData(Remote remoteObj) {
        this.testVar = remoteObj.getVar();
        testTextArea.appendText("TestVar: " + testVar);
    }    
}
```

The slight disadvantage here is that the initialization of the controller is spread over multiple methods, executed at different points in the controller's life cycle. Other options include setting the controller in code, instead of specifying the controller class in the FXML file, or using a controller factory. The disadvantage of setting the controller in code is that if you use a tool (such as Scene Builder) for designing the FXML, it will not be aware of the controller class being used. Using a controller factory is more complex, but avoids this issue.